# Image color changed after converting from numpy array to PIL image python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert the image that I read using `cv2.imread` which is store in numpy array to PIL Image object , the color of Image will be changed  Here is the code

```
I=cv2.imread("Image.jpg")
PILImage=Image.fromarray(I,mode='RGB')
```

How can get back my original Image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OpenCV likes to treat images as having BGR layers instead of RGB layers. Adding

```
I = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

will swap layers to what you expect.

Comment: Great this was exactly what I needed! Thanks Dave! This worked for me opening a .jpeg editing it then saving as a .png.